# error duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zze.class

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-login

I am creating **Facebook login** system with **Firebase**. But when I compile the project, it gives me:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/common/api/zze.class

**build.gradle (project):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zihadrizkyef.belajar_facebooklogin"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: Change your `buildToolsVersion` to 25.0.0 and I don't think you need multiDex here because you don't include big library in your project. So you need to remove it or commenting it.

Comment: If i delete it, android studio gives me multidex error.. i don't remember the error quotes

Comment: Hmm..Did you have another library included in `libs` directory of your project?

Comment: I didn't put any library at all. I just use gradle.

Comment: Let put it aside, how about using `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'` ?

Comment: Still gives me same error
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zze.class`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128765/discussion-between-zihadrizkyef-and---).

Comment: also add exclude for facebook dependancy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the Firebase libraries must be the same version. Use version 10.0.0 of `firebase-auth`:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project, there are some duplicate files in different jars or libs, I add some codes int my app build.gradle like this:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INFTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INFTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INFtice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INFcense.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.properties'
}
```

And it works.

I think you may include some other jars that include "com/google/android/gms/common/api/zze.class" or whole jar.

UMeng jars contains protobuf ,and my model contains too, so I exclude two protobuf-java file in build.gradle ,in packagingOptions.

Comment: where shall i put that code?
btw i dont know which jar is duplicating

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```